# Fetch upstream from another repo and then push the changes in my local branch

Tags: git, upstream-branch

I have two projects one is a mirror from another and I have a branch in the no mirror project that I need to move to the mirror project.

I'm doing the next:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/my/nomirrorProject.git
git fetch upstream upstreamBranch:mylocalbranch
```

But I'm getting the next error message:

```
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/myLocalBranch of non-bare repository

git push origin mylocalbranch
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `mylocalbranch` is currently checked out. As such, you cannot write its ref directly. You need to switch to a different branch, use pull or fetch into a local branch with another name

Comment: I got the same error with a new branch

Comment: I doubt it, unless you checked out the new branch too. Which is not supported, as the error messages clearly states: "Refusing to fetch into _current branch_ of non-bare repository"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Unless you know *exactly what you are doing*, do not use the `git fetch upstream upstreamBranch:mylocalbranch` syntax.  Similarly, do not use `git fetch origin theirbranch:mybranch`.  Instead, use `git fetch upstream` followed by one of:

- `git checkout` or `git switch`, or
- `git merge`, or
- `git rebase`

depending on your intended goal.

## What you're doing

Git is all about *commits*.  Git isn't really about branches, though branch names help you (and Git) *find* commits; Git is about the *commits*.  Git isn't really about files either, though each commit *contains* files.  This means you need to know, first, what a commit is and does for you, and, second, that a Git *repository* consists of several database plus some extra stuff to make them useful for you.  The first (and usually biggest by far) database holds the commits and other objects.

#### Commits

Commits, in Git:

- Are numbered.  Every Git commit has a globally (across *every Git repository ever*, even if it's not related to your Git repository) unique ID, which Git calls a *hash ID* or an *object ID* (OID).  This is how two Git repositories, when they meet on the street (or on the net), decide whether they have a commit in common, or not: by comparing these IDs.  These hash IDs are very large and ugly; they *look* random to humans, although they're not random at all; and humans basically never use them directly (that would drive us crazy).
- Hold snapshots and metadata:

  - Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file—or more precisely, but it sounds redundant, every file that it has.  The redundant-sounding phrase takes care of the fact that some commits have new files added, and some subsequent commits may have files removed.  Each commit, once made, is frozen for all time, so its saved files are available forever.

    The files inside the commits are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only format in which they're compressed and de-duplicated.  So the fact that one archive (commit) mostly re-uses files from some previous commit means that these archives take very little space.  In fact, if you make a new commit that *completely* re-uses old files—this can happen in any number of ways—the new commit takes no space at all to hold the files, just a little space to hold the metadata.
  - Meanwhile, each commit holds some metadata.  This is also frozen for all time (the hashing scheme depends on this).  The metadata include things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  They include a log message, where you get to write *why* you made the commit.  (Don't just say that you changed line 42 or whatever: Git can figure that out from the snapshot.  Say *why* you changed line 42.  What was wrong with it before?  What *behavior* did the program exhibit that was bad, that is now corrected by this change?)

    In this metadata, Git stores some information that *Git* needs: specifically, the raw hash ID(s) of a list of earlier commits.  Git calls these the *parents* of the commit.

Usually there is exactly one hash ID in this metadata list.  That is, most commits have just one parent.  These are your ordinary commits.

By holding the hash ID of a single parent, each commit "points to" its predecessor.  This makes a backwards chain of commits.  For instance, suppose we have some commit with some hash that we'll call `H`, and we draw it with an arrow coming out of it, representing this backwards pointer to its parent commit:

```
            <-H
```

The earlier commit to which `H` points has some other different hash ID, but, just like `H`, stores a snapshot and metadata, so let's draw this commit as commit `G` with a backwards arrow coming out of it:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Commit `G` thus points to a still-earlier commit.  Let's call it `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

`F` points backwards yet again, and so on.  This *is* the history in the repository, starting (ending?) at commit `H` and working (backwards), one commit at a time.

The history in a repository, in other words, is nothing more or less than the *commits* in the repository.  Each commit has a full snapshot of every file, frozen in time as of the form that file had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  And, each commit has a unique number; we're just using these uppercase letters to let our feeble human brains manage them here.

Note that the very first commit ever made in some repository has *no* parent, because it can't have one.  So it just has no arrow coming out of it.  We could draw an entire chain of eight commits this way, then:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

Commit `H` is the last commit, at the start (end?) of history, with `A` as the first commit, at the end (start?) of history.  Git works backwards, so history "starts at the end".

#### This is where branch names come in

Git needs a fast way to *find* the *last* commit.  It's easy for us to see the last one in these simple drawings, but real repositories can have thousands or millions of commits and any drawings you make will generally get very messy (this depends on the repository).  So to provide an easy way to *find* the last commit, Git uses a *branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

The *name* `main` simply contains the raw hash ID of the *last commit in the chain*.  From here, Git will work backwards as usual.

If we want to have more than one *branch name*, we just create another name, also pointing to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

#### Using commits

While commits store files (snapshots) and metadata, the stored files are read-only, and in a format—a Git internal object—that only Git can read in the first place.  No other programs can read these files, and nothing—not even Git itself—can *overwrite* them.  But that's not how our computer programs want to work.  They want to read and write real files, not weird Git-ized internal objects.

To *use* a commit, then, Git has to *copy all the files out of the snapshot*.  This is what `git checkout` or `git switch` does.<sup><1</sup>  You pick a *commit* you want Git to extract, and run:

```
git switch develop
```

for instance to pick out commit `H`.  Git now extracts the files into a work area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*, where you can see them and, if you like, *change* them too.

Note that these are *your* files to do whatever you like with.  Git isn't using them.  Git will, if you tell it to, eventually copy them back to make them ready for a *new* commit, using another area Git calls the *staging area*, which we won't describe properly here.  But for now these are *your* files.  If you run `git checkout` or `git switch` again, Git might *remove* these files and put in *other* files.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can use either command; `git switch` is the newer and less-powerful, therefore less-dangerous one.  Think of an overly complicated Swiss army knife: do you want the one where there's a self-starting chainsaw blade, or do you want the one that only has a regular knife blade?  Sometimes you might want the chainsaw, but it's probably better to keep that as a separate tool.

---

#### Updating a branch name

Let's look now, briefly, at how a branch name gets updated when you run `git commit`.  You've run `git switch develop` to select commit `H` to work on.  Git attached the special name `HEAD` to the name `develop` to remember that this is the *current branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

You make changes to various files and run `git add` (for reasons we're skipping over), and then run `git commit`.  Git prepares a new commit, gathering metadata—your name and email address, your log message, and for Git's history purposes, the raw hash ID of commit `H`—and makes a new snapshot of *all* files, taking into account the added updated and/or new and/or removed files too.  These all go together into a new commit `I`, whose parent is existing commit `H`.  Let's draw it in:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

I've drawn `I` on a new line, and left out the names, on purpose.  Let's put the names back in now.  **Git has done something very sneaky here** as the name `develop`—the one `HEAD` is attached to—no longer points to commit `H`!

```
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we add another new commit `J`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Note that there are now two commits that are on `develop` that are not on `main`.  If we `git switch main`, Git will *remove* from our working tree all the files from commit `J`, and put in place instead all the files from commit `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We're now "on" `main` again, using the files from commit `H`.  The newest branch-`main` commit is commit `H`, while the newest branch-`develop` commit is commit `J`.

Let's make another new branch now, named `topic`, and switch to it.  This will also point to commit `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, topic (HEAD)
```

Now let's change some file(s), `git add`, and `git commit`.  This makes a new commit `K` whose parent is `H` (not `I`, not `J`, but `H`), because `H` is the *current commit* as found by the *current branch name* `topic`.  Then, having made commit `K`, Git writes the hash ID of commit `K` into the *name* `topic`:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- topic (HEAD)
```

These are our branches: `H` is the *latest* commit on `main`, `J` is the *latest* on `develop`, and `K` is the *latest* on `topic`.  History works backwards from here, so from `K` we go back to `H`, then `G`, and so on; from `J` we go back to `I`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on; and from `H`, we go back to `G` and so on.

**This also means that all commits up through `H` are on all three branches.**  In Git, commits are often on *more than one branch*.

#### Branch names are not the only kinds of names in Git

Besides branch names, we can also have *tag names*, for instance.  The key differences between these two kinds of names are:

- You can't get "on" a tag name: `git checkout v1.2`, if `v1.2` is a tag name, produces what Git calls a *detached HEAD*, and `git switch v1.2` gives you an error unless you add `--detached` to allow Git to go into detached-HEAD mode.
- Tag names do not automatically update.  This is an outgrowth of the fact that you can't get "on" a tag name.  When you make a new commit, Git updates the *branch* name that you're on, and in detached-HEAD mode, you are on *no* branch at all.
- Tag names get *shared*.

To explain that last point, it's time to talk about clones and `git fetch`.

#### Clones

I mentioned earlier that a Git repository consists primarily of two databases.  One database holds commits and other internal objects, all found by object IDs.  (Commits are one of four internal Git object types, though to use Git you mostly don't have to know this—unlike the rest of what I'm writing here.)

The other primary database holds names: branch names, tag names, and all of Git's other names.  These names all holds object IDs: mostly commit IDs (with tag names being a sometimes notable exception, but then the tags wind up pointing to a commit indirectly, so that you mostly don't have to know about *annotated tag objects*.  We will skip over this detail here, but it crops up later when you go to create tags.

When you *clone* a Git repository, with:

```
git clone <url>
```

you're instructing your Git to:

1. create a new, empty directory (or use an existing empty directory) to create a new, empty repository;
2. add a thing Git calls a *remote*—a short name that holds a URL, and the standard first "remote" is named `origin`—so that your Git can call up some other Git repository any time you like;
3. call up that other Git repository now, and get all of their *commits*, but don't—quite—copy their *branch* names;
4. *rename* their branch names instead, but do (usually) get all their tag names; and
5. create *one* branch name in your new clone.

So you have your Git software copy their *commits and other objects* database, but you don't have your Git copy their *branch names*.  Instead, you have your Git take each of their *branch* names and turn those into *remote-tracking names*.

A *remote-tracking name* is essentially<sup>2</sup> formed by taking their *branch* name, such as `main` or `develop` or `feature/tall` or whatever, and sticking your own *remote* name—`origin` for this initial clone—in front to get `origin/main`, `origin/develop`, `origin/feature/tall`, and so on.  Your Git does this with all their *branch* names.  Your Git doesn't do this with their tag names: if they have a `v1.2` and a `v2.0`, your Git will create your own tag names spelled `v1.2` and `v2.0` too.

So *tag* names are different from *branch* names in this extra way: not only are they not supposed to move—they should identify one particular commit *forever*, rather than the *latest commit on some branch*—but they also get *shared*.  Branch names aren't *shared*.

---

<sup>2</sup>This glosses over a lot of detail.

---

#### Adding remotes and using `git fetch`

You can have as many remotes as you like.  The *first* one is normally called `origin`, and `git clone` makes this one for you.  In fact, `git clone url` is basically short for a six-command sequence, five of which are Git commands:

1. `mkdir` (or whatever command your OS uses to make a new empty directory), with all the Git commands being run in the new directory;
2. `git init`, to create an empty repository in this new directory;
3. `git remote add origin url`, to add `origin` as the remote;
4. any extra `git config` commands needed (sometimes there are a few);
5. `git fetch origin`, to get all the commits and rename the branches; and
6. `git checkout` / `git switch` with the "create a new branch" option.

The branch that your Git checks out in step 6 is the one you choose with the `-b` option to your `git clone` command.  If you don't give a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git software which branch name their repository recommends.  Your Git then uses that branch name, which your Git renamed to `origin/whatever`, to create your branch *`whatever`*, pointing to the *same commit* as your `origin/whatever`.

If their recommended name is `main`, then, you might end up with this:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/topic
```

Note how you have one *remote-tracking name* for each of their *branch* names, plus one branch name of your own.

You can now run `git remote add upstream` if you like, to add a remote named `upstream`.  Give a URL that your Git should call up.  Then run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

with no arguments, and your Git will call up that Git.  They will list out, for your Git, all of *their* branch names and the commit hash IDs that go with those branch names.

Because of your earlier `git clone`, your Git probably already has most if not all of these commits, found via your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  For any commits that they *do* have, that you don't, your Git will ask their Git to package up and send over these commits.  That might include some extra commits, or not.  In any case, your Git now takes each of their (`upstream`'s) *branch* names and *renames them* to form names like `upstream/main`:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/develop, upstream/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main, upstream/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/topic
           \
            L   <-- upstream/topic
```

Here, they have the same three branch names on `upstream` as your Git found on the Git you're calling `origin`.  But `upstream`'s `topic` names commit `L`, not commit `K`.  So your Git obtained commit `L` from them.  Your Git did not need to obtain any other commits—you had the rest already—and then your Git created your `upstream/*` names.

#### What you're doing with `git fetch upstream theirbranch:mybranch`

Above, I describe the normal operation of `git fetch remote`, when you don't use any extra arguments.  If you *do* use extra arguments, such as:

```
git fetch origin main
```

or:

```
git fetch upstream main
```

the remaining arguments after the *`remote`* are what Git calls a *refspec*.

A refspec can get complicated, but it comes in two relatively simple forms.  One form is like this: just a branch or tag name.  Git will figure out from context whether it's a branch name or tag name, if Git can do that; if not, you must help Git out by telling Git explicitly that this is a branch or tag name, which we won't show here.

The more complicated form has two names separated by a colon `:` character:

```
git fetch upstream main:upmain
```

The name on the left is a *source*, which for `git fetch` is the remote repository's branch or tag name.<sup>3</sup>  The name on the right is the *destination:* for `git fetch`, that's the branch or tag name you'd like your Git to *create or update* in *your* repository.

This update operation works by *shoving a new hash ID into the name*, if the name exists, or by creating the branch or tag name holding the hash ID, if the name does not yet exist.

If you're on your `main` branch like this:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/develop, upstream/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main, upstream/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/topic
           \
            L   <-- upstream/topic
```

then your *current branch* is `main` and your *current commit* is commit `H`.

If you were to run:

```
git fetch upstream topic:topic
```

that would tell your Git to go over to `upstream`, find that they have commit `L` as their `topic`, bring over commit `L` if needed—it's not needed because you have it now—and then *create or update* your branch name `topic` to point to commit `L`.  Since you have no branch name `topic`, your Git could do this, producing:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/develop, upstream/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main, upstream/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/topic
           \
            L   <-- topic, upstream/topic
```

Note that your *current branch* `main` continues to point to commit `H`.

But if you ask your Git to:

```
git fetch upstream topic:main
```

you're now telling your Git to find that they have their `topic` referring to commit `L`, and to write commit `L`'s hash ID into your name `main`.  If your Git *did* do this, you would have:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/develop, upstream/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main, upstream/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/topic
           \
            L   <-- main (HEAD), upstream/topic
```

This would indicate that your current branch `main`'s current commit is `L`.  The problem here is that all the *files in your working tree* (and index) *came out of commit `H`*, not out of commit `L`.  They will still match the files in commit `H`.

Your Git therefore says *no, I won't move the name `main` to commit `L`, as that would disrupt the smooth workings of your current checkout*.  Which it would, so don't do that.  Just run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

and then, if you really *want* your name `main` to point to commit `L`, use `git reset --hard upstream/topic` to achieve that, knowing exactly what `git reset --hard` does.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>3</sup>Refspecs are used with `git push` as well, although their interpretation is a bit different here, and for `git push` the source is *your* repository, not the remote repository.)

<sup>4</sup>Remember that `git reset --hard` means *if I have unsaved work, destroy it irrecoverably*.  Git will do that!  You should probably make sure you have no unsaved work first.